# Accessing introspect endpoint , failed:connection refused kong, keycload,OIDC

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, kong, kong-plugin

I am getting a connection refused response from the server when i try to hit the the endpoint via the proxy i have created on kong.
The curl command i am using to hit the proxy -

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8000/listProducts/'
--header 'Accept: application/json'
--header 'Authorization: Bearer token'
```

to get the token I use the following curl -

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/experimental/protocol/openid-connect/token'
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
--data-urlencode 'username=username'
--data-urlencode 'password=password'
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password'
--data-urlencode 'client_id=myapp'
```

The Client protocol is open-connect and the access type is public.

The config i have done in the Oidc plugin:

```
consumer:

response type:
code:
introspection endpoint: http://{MyHostIP}:8180/auth/realms/experimental/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect

filters:

bearer only: yes

ssl verify: no

session secret:

introspection endpoint auth method:

realm: experimental

redirect after logout uri: /

scope: openid

token endpoint auth method:

client_secret_post:

logout path: /logout

client id: kong

discovery: https://{MyHostIP}:8180/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration

client secret: myClientSecret

recovery page path:

redirect uri path:
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

How did u deployed Keycloak? I see 2 points:

- Your discovery endpoint is https
- Your introspection endpoint is just http

Also, if you are using Docker to deploy Kong + Keycloak, go to your hosts file and add a new line with your local ip with MyHostIP.

`sudo nano /etc/hosts`

Then add

`your.ip.address.     keycloak-host`

Update the docker-compose file

```
kong:
    build:
      context: kong/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    extra_hosts:
      - "Keycloak-host:your.ip.address"
```

Now configure your introspection and discovery url using the keycloak-host

Ex: `http://keycloak-host:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect`

If you need a functional example about Kong + openID + Keycloak, check [this](https://github.com/blitzrok/kong-oidc-keycloak) repo.